# Backup a List from the site to meet the following requirements:

Tags: list, backup, 70-667

I am studying the 70-667 exam and there is a question with two different answers on different pdf files.

The question is following:

You have a SharePoint server 2010 site. You need to back up a list to meet the following requirements:

- Back up the permission
- Back up the version history information
- Minimize the time to perform the backup.

What should you do?

- **A)** From the command prompt, run stdsam.exe and specify the backup
  operation
- **B)** From central administration, open Site or List export and start
  the export.

My thought was that the answer is B) and it was correct in the pdf file  but I found in another pdf file that A) is correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I answer this one, I've seen you ask a few of these types of questions.  You really want to avoid using downloadable exam dumps or poorly assembled PDF answer sheets.  They're not usually right and don't really offer any knowledge.  I've neverf gone wrong with MeasureUp learning packages and they're not terribly expensive.

For this question I'd go with the command prompt / PowerShell.  You can preserve permissions and version history with the appropriate flags and command line (whether STSADM or PowerShell) is much quicker than navigating the Central Administration GUI.

Hope that helps.